# How to move paired data from one data frame column to another dataframe while keeping the same order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file with a list of NBA players and their average fantasy draft positions. I'm trying to add this 'ADP' value to a data frame that has all of their stats for the season. However, the players are not in the same order in both files so I must iterate through them and compare the list of players, only adding the ADP value when the player names match. 
this is the loop I'm using currently

```
data['ADP'] = ""
for row in data:
for rdw in adp:
    if row[0] == rdw[1]:
        data["ADP"]=adp["ADP"]
    else:
        pass
```

this adds the ADP value from one data frame to the other but it adds the whole thing on the first match instead of adding the adp values one at a time. Any help would be appreciated, im not locked into using this style of loop I just want it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data.join(adp, on=SOME_COLUMN)
```

You might need to do a bit more than this depending on your data frames; I don't know what your column names are.

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you a definitive solution since I don't know what your data looks like. But here's an example for NFL. I don't do this for `"Adp"`, but I do a lot of fantasy sports stuff with data so lots of merging/joining datasets and data sources.

Few things you might want to look up first:

1. What sort of join do you want? Is it Left, Right, Outer, Inner? Look those up because it'll determine what you end up with it. Here, I just simply did an outer which will include both datasets, leaving nulls where it can't find a match, and then I deal with those later. Be careful, just because there are nulls, it doesn't mean there isn't a match, it could be a case of the 2 datasets represented differently. 1 data source may use `'Odell Beckham'`, while another uses `'Odell Beckham Jr.'` Same guy, same name, but slightly different with `'Jr.'` used on one...makes a difference when trying to join.
2. Identify what your unique values are. You could just match up on player name, but what if 2 players have the same name? So you may need to use a combination of columns. I've found Player Name, and Position usually takes care of it. There may be an occasional 1 or 2 anomalies, but a) I usually don't care as it pertains to some 3rd string or practice squad player, or b) I can just deal with that 1 on an individual basis (Like I think there's two Michael Thomas WR...one obviously in NO, and then another backup somewhere. I usually just find that backup and remove him from my dataset).

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([
['Derrick Henry',   'TEN',  25, 'RB',   15  ,15,    303 ,1540   ,16 ,73 ,74 ,5.1    ,102.7  ,5],
['Ezekiel Elliott', 'DAL',  24, 'RB'    ,16 ,16 ,301    ,1357   ,12 ,78 ,33 ,4.5    ,84.8   ,3],
['Nick Chubb',  'CLE',  24, 'RB',   16  ,16,    298,    1494    ,8  ,62 ,88 ,5.0    ,93.4   ,3],
['Christian McCaffrey', 'CAR',  23, 'RB'    ,16 ,16 ,287    ,1387   ,15 ,57 ,84 ,4.8    ,86.7   ,1],
['Chris Carson',    'SEA',  25, 'RB'    ,15 ,15 ,278    ,1230   ,7  ,75 ,59,    4.4 ,82.0   ,7],
['Joe Mixon',   'CIN',  23, 'RB'    ,16 ,15 ,278    ,1137   ,5  ,56 ,41 ,4.1    ,71.1   ,0],
['Leonard Fournette',   'JAX'   ,24 ,'RB'   ,15 ,15 ,265    ,1152,  3,  55  ,81,    4.3,    76.8,   1],
['Dalvin Cook', 'MIN',  24, 'RB'    ,14 ,14 ,250    ,1135   ,13 ,60 ,75 ,4.5    ,81.1   ,4],
['Marlon Mack', 'IND',  23, 'RB'    ,14 ,12 ,247    ,1091   ,8  ,67,    63  ,4.4    ,77.9,  0]],
        columns=['Player','Tm','Age','Pos','G','GS','Att','Yds','TD','1D','Lng','Y/A','Y/G','Fmb'])



adp = pd.DataFrame([
['Joe Mixon',   'CIN',  23, 'RB',7],
['Ezekiel Elliott', 'DAL',  24, 'RB',2],
['Nick Chubb',  'CLE',  24, 'RB',23],
['Christian McCaffrey', 'CAR',  23, 'RB',1],
['Marlon Mack', 'IND',  23, 'RB',34],
['Leonard Fournette',   'JAX'   ,24 ,'RB',4],
['Mitch Trubiskey', 'CHI'   ,24 ,'QB',104],
['Leonard Fournette',   'JAX'   ,24 ,'RB',4],
['Dalvin Cook', 'MIN',  24, 'RB',17],
['Derrick Henry',   'TEN',  25, 'RB',10 ]],
columns=['Player','Tm','Age','Pos','Adp'])

key_cols = ['Player','Tm','Pos']
data = data.merge(adp[key_cols + ['Adp']], how='outer', on=key_cols)
```